# Mesosphere Cloud Formation Template Using Existing VPC/NAT

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, mesosphere

I am using the existing single master Mesosphere DCOS cloud formation template:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mesosphere.io/dcos/stable/cloudformation/single-master.cloudformation.json

I am trying to figure out how to indicate that I want to spin this up in an existing VPC that is already configured with a NAT/Internet gateway.

New to cloud formation and can't find any docs on the Mesosphere site around what the template actually creates and why.  In addition there doesn't appear to be an all up manual setup tutorial.  Just this template.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the CF template, just delete the VPC resource, include the vpc-id as a parameter and change all the references to the VPC resource to point the new parameter.

In the same way you could replace the subnets in the template and remove the NAT instance.

Answer (score 0):

I have made the changes in cloudformation script to install mesosphere in existing VPC/NAT.

https://github.com/navidurrahman/dcos-cloudformation

Let me know, if you face any problems

Comment: What should the value of "ResolverDnsParam" be? my stack creation is failing always.

Comment: The default value of the Resolvers is 169.254.169.253. Where does this value come from?

Answer (score 0):

This cloud formation template installs dcos version 1.3. I have written a terraform module for latest mesosphere installation.

https://github.com/navidurrahman/terraform_mesosphere